# How Do You Force Quit (i.e. Kill/Crash) the Foreground App on iOS Devices Without a Home Button?

Tags: iphone, ios

On iOS devices with a home button, it was possible to kill the foreground application by:

1. Pressing & holding the power button until the "slide to power off" screen appeared, then
2. Pressing & holding the home button until the foreground app is killed

This would cause the foreground app to exit immediately. I've used this occasionally over the years when a bug in an app was severe enough that a regular "quit" triggered by swiping up on the multitasking view was not sufficient to get the app back into a usable state. It has saved me from having to un-install/re-install misbehaving apps on a few occasions.

I can't find any official reference to the above "force quit" procedure on Apple's current support article (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201412).

Googling "force quit" is also not helpful, as the results are full of articles giving instructions on how to quit applications from the multitasking view (which is not actually "force quitting"/killing).

Does anyone know the procedure to kill the foreground app on iOS devices without a home button?

Comment: Try touch accommodations

Comment: @anki That's a great idea, unfortunately it doesn't work. :-(

Comment: Swipe up and hold to gain access to the multitasking interface.
Find the app you’d like to kill.
Swipe up on the app to kill it.

Comment: @slartibartfast As mentioned above, this just triggers a regular quit & doesn't send an immediate kill signal.